# Why sometimes I get an "Invalid transaction object" exception?

Tags: delphi, dbx

Is there something wrong with this code?
Sometimes I get an unhandled "Invalid transaction object" exception in it:

```
procedure BlaBla;
var
  TD: TDBXTransaction;
begin
  TD := SQLConnection.BeginTransaction;
  try
    SQLConnection.ExecuteDirect('some sql command');
    SQLConnection.ExecuteDirect('some sql command');
    SQLConnection.CommitFreeAndNil(TD);
  except
    SQLConnection.RollbackFreeAndNil(TD);
  end;
end;
```

This exception is being raised to the user, so I assume it's raised by RollbackFreeAndNil, since all rest is inside a try..except.

Should I wrap RollbackFreeAndNil with another try..except? What a mess.

I'm using Delphi 2009, DBX with Firebird 2.1 and Devart's driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that SQLConnection.BeginTransaction returns nil if SQLConnection is not Connected to the database. And then I get the exception of invalid transaction object.

I never expected that. It should try to connect or raise an exception. Returning nil doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

What would happen if CommitFreeAndNil threw an exception?

RollbackFreeAndNil would be called. Would TD be valid then?

You're eating the exception, and hence the evidence. Don't do that; re-throw:

```
procedure BlaBla;
var
  TD: TDBXTransaction;
begin
  TD := SQLConnection.BeginTransaction;
  try
    SQLConnection.ExecuteDirect('some sql command');
    SQLConnection.ExecuteDirect('some sql command');
  except
    SQLConnection.RollbackFreeAndNil(TD);
    raise;
  end;
  SQLConnection.CommitFreeAndNil(TD);
end;
```

Comment: And when re-throwing, you could use the new inner-exception-feature, as shown by Jim McKeeth at CodeRage III.

Comment: Thanks Craig, please, read again my question because I added more information after you answer.

Comment: The problem was not related to my try..except block.

Comment: My first sentence: "What would happen if CommitFreeAndNil threw an exception?" Your solution: "And then I get the exception of invalid transaction object." Yup, completely unrelated!

Answer (score 1):

some times is that you execute varius procedures with a component like cxdbmemo and give you thats error. You have to remove that component (or somthing like this) and do your transaction normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLConnection.DBXConnection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);
```